# Split multiple columns with multiple delimiters; Newly-formed columns should have count of original values

Tags: python, pandas, split, count

I'm new to python programming. I work on data where subsets of some attributes are obtained inside a single super-set (i.e. column/attribute) (with non-alphanumeric separators).

Representative data:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x/x/z/z/z | i\i\i\j |
| 2 | y/y/z/w/w/w | k\k\i |

Preferred output:

| col1 | w_col2 | x_col2 | y_col2 | z_col2 | i_col3 | j_col3 | k_col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |

What I generally do:

1. Find unique entries for such columns
2. Split all such columns individually; Apply column prefixes (optionally); Store as new dataframe
3. Apply value_counts() on axis 1
4. Concat with original dataframe

Fortunately, the dataset is small with known columns to work on. However, I would like to know if there is a better (compact) way to approach this.

---

Edit:

- Added new columns where values are to be treated (cast) as numbers (since they are counts)

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x/x/z/z/z | i\i\i\j | 0-2-4-2 | 1_2_5_3 |
| 2 | y/y/z/w/w/w | k\k\i | 1-3-2-2 | 4_1_3_4 |

New preferred output:

| col1 | w_col2 | x_col2 | y_col2 | z_col2 | i_col3 | j_col3 | k_col3 | 0_col4 | 1_col4 | 2_col4 | 3_col4 | 0_col5 | 1_col5 | 2_col5 | 3_col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 4 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proposal using `df.stack` , then `series.split` folowed by `series.explode` and `pd.crosstab`

```
u = df[['col2','col3']].stack().str.split(r"\\|/").explode()
v = u.add("_"+ u.index.get_level_values(1))

out = pd.crosstab(v,v.index.get_level_values(0)).T.rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
```

---

```
print(out)

   i_col3  j_col3  k_col3  w_col2  x_col2  y_col2  z_col2
0       3       1       0       0       2       0       3
1       1       0       2       3       0       2       1
```

EDIT:

As per edited question you can do similar steps for col4 and col5 then concat:

```
u = df[['col2','col3']].stack().str.split(r"\\|/").explode()
v = u.add("_"+ u.index.get_level_values(1))

a = df[['col4','col5']].stack().str.split("-|_",expand=True).unstack()
a.columns = a.columns.map("{0[0]}_{0[1]}".format)

out = (pd.concat((df[['col1']],
                  pd.crosstab(v,v.index.get_level_values(0))
                     .T.rename_axis(index=None,columns=None),
                  a),axis=1))
print(out)
```

---

```
   col1  i_col3  j_col3  k_col3  w_col2  x_col2  y_col2  z_col2 0_col4 0_col5  \
0     1       3       1       0       0       2       0       3      0      1   
1     2       1       0       2       3       0       2       1      1      4   

  1_col4 1_col5 2_col4 2_col5 3_col4 3_col5  
0      2      2      4      5      2      3  
1      3      1      2      3      2      4
```

Comment: **Note** : You can use `df[['col1']].join(out)` to include `col1` in the final output.

Comment: @nyasa, how do you want to join it to the output. I am currently not with my computer so can't test but if you do `pd.DataFrame(df['col4'].str.split(r'//').tolist())` and then join it to the output. Is that what you want? If not probably edit the question or post a new one as you think is best :)

Comment: @nyasa try `df['col4'].str.split(r'//',expand=True)` may be :-) this should give you a dataframe of the values splitted into seperate columns. Then you can join the dfs. Sorry for the inconvenience, I stepped out for some work and currently not in front of the computer

Comment: @nyasa edited with full code for updated question.